# Информационная модель хранения древовидной структуры в реляционной базе данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, nested-sets

Добрый день, сейчас изучаю базы данных и возник такой вопрос, где я могу почитать о

> Информационной модели хранения древовидной структуры в реляционной БД
>   ???

Спасибо

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При работе с древовидными структурами следует помнить о четырех наиболее распространенных паттернах:

1. Список соседства (ключ id - родитель parent_id)
2. Перечисление путей (1/5/21/128/ - номера идентификаторы родителей)
3. Таблица замыканий (Closure table)
4. Вложенные множества (Nested Set)

Это четыре основных паттерна, которые обычно используются для организации древовидных структур. Читать можно где угодно, если достанете книгу "Джо Селко. SQL"/"Joe Celko's. SQL for smatties: advanced SQL programming" - они там отлично описаны.